# Azure Data Factory : Self Hosted IR : High Availability

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, high-availability, on-premises-instances

So I am trying to connect two nodes of the ADF Selfhosted IR into High Availability Mode. My nodes are on a private Azure Network and tested if both of them can see each other -- Ping Test is successful.

On reading, I was told that I need to set up inbound rules for both the nodes to enable HA -- This is done as well.

Still the "Is HA Enabled on the ADF Monitoring Tool" is coming as false.

Could somebody tell if I am missing steps here?

Answer (score 0):

It was simple really. I made the mistake of setting two different IR's on my ADF.